# create GUI for selecting and filtering of Image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, filter, gui-designer

i would like to  practice on  designing GUI in matlab  ,this GUI  has two  function  -one for selecting of image and second for filtering,general structure of such Graphical interface is very  simple
[image]

and here is two code -one which select image after pressing on select image  and second which filters image using simple average filter after clicking on filter image

```
function select_image_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to select_image (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
[filename, pathname] = uigetfile({'*.jpg';'*.png'},'File select');
image=strcat(pathname,filename);
axes(handles.axes1);
imshow(image);
```

and for filtering

```
function filter_image_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to filter_image (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
h = ones(5,5) / 25;
Filtered_image = imfilter(image,h);
axes(handles.axes2);
imshow(Filtered_image);
```

but when i run code, i selected simple this file

[image]

i got following error

```
Error using imfilter
Expected input number 1, A, to be one of these types:

numeric, logical

Instead its type was matlab.graphics.primitive.Image.

Error in imfilter>parse_inputs (line 186)
validateattributes(a,{'numeric' 'logical'},{'nonsparse'},mfilename,'A',1);

Error in imfilter (line 118)
[a, h, boundary, sameSize, convMode] = parse_inputs(varargin{:});

Error in filter_image_filter_image_Callback (line 92)
Filtered_image = imfilter(image,h);

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95)
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in filter_image (line 42)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in @(hObject,eventdata)filter_image('filter_image_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


Error while evaluating UIControl Callback
```

why happens this? thanks in advance

Comment: `image` is the name of  function in Matlab so you might get a conflict since you named a variable image. Try changing the name of that variable

Comment: there is one problem , from second   function i can't  access to  variable in first function, i mean  variable scope is violated, so  should i declare it as global?

Comment: i have solved  and i will post my code

Answer (score 0):

based on my question and related to problem, i have decided to  include my solution as well  ,which i found after  researching, here is  fragments of my code, first of thanks to @ Benoit_11 for his  advice and i have changed name  from image to selected_image, related to my  comment about  accessing one variable(in this case image)  form another  function  i used function getimage, so there is my complete solution

```
function select_image_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to select_image (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
[filename, pathname] = uigetfile({'*.jpg';'*.png'},'File select');
selected_image=strcat(pathname,filename);
axes(handles.axes1);
imshow(selected_image);

% --- Executes on button press in filter_image.
function filter_image_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to filter_image (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
selected_image=getimage(handles.axes1);
h = ones(5,5) / 25;
Filtered_image = imfilter(selected_image,h);
axes(handles.axes2);
imshow(Filtered_image);
```

[image]